# Select a poster frame for video thumbnails in Photos app?

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app, video-editing

Is there a way to select a Poster Frame to use as the thumbnail of a video in your Camera Roll?

For example, many of my videos fade up from black. Because of this, the thumbnails are black and it's difficult to distinguish between videos. It also looks bad if a business is presenting videos to potential clients on an iPad.

Can  video poster frame thumbnails be added on  iOS(preferably) or Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set Poster Frames via Photos.app on macOS.

Setting via the Mac **does** sync the custom poster frame to your iOS devices via iCloud Photos.

1. Play a video in Photos for Mac
2. Pause the video at the intended frame
3. Press the gear icon and select `Set Poster Frame`

[image: Set Poster Frame]

---

In macOS **Big Sur**, the [gear icon has been removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413945/how-do-i-get-the-gear-icon-to-show-for-video-playback-in-macos-photos) and this feature has moved:

1. Press the **Edit** button.
2. Scrub to the intended video frame.
3. Select `Make Poster Frame` from the pop-up.

In macOS **Monterey**, this pop-up has been removed. Instead, select "Make Poster Frame" from the Image menu.

[image: Photos app for macOS Make Poster Frame]

Comment: not working anymore in newer Photos releases :/

Comment: @pfincent a Monterey fix is at the bottom of the answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: the option is there in the Image menu, using it does not update the key photo though, even when restarting the application

Comment: For Big Sur, where is an "Edit button"?

Comment: @JimL. You need to click edit, select frame in video and use top menu "Image->Make Poster Frame". Without clicking edit button the menu item will be grayed out

Comment: I found something, but it’s not a button. Anyway, after “make poster frame” and “done”, Photos stops offering a play triangle!