# How do I get the gear icon to show for video playback in macOS Photos?

Tags: macos, video, photos.app, big-sur, ui

Using the Photos app on macOS Big Sur, when I play a video in my library, I see this as the playback bar. [image: screenshot]

However, according to various guides I see on the web, the playback bar ought to look something like this.

[image: screenshot]

What is the issue here? Is this a change in Big Sur? I am looking for the options that the gear  menu usually provides like 'Trim' and 'Export Frame to Pictures'.

Comment: It looks like it has been removed in macOS Big Sur, I'am currently looking for Photos.app *changelog* so I can confirm (I only saw few people saying this on different forums). You still can *Trim* a video by clicking on the **Edit** button on the top right hand corner of the application's window and also on Quicktime.app with CMD⌘+T. Concerning the *Export Frame to Pictures*, a bit tricky but you can succeed by opening the video with Quicktime.app, pause the video at the desired timecode and copy/paste the current image to a new Preview.app file. You can also use iMovie.app to do it.

Comment: @tama Ah, that's unfortunate... not so straightforward. I ended up using VLC to do it, in fact. Thanks for checking into this though.

Comment: This answer no longer works for Big Sur, as the gear icon is gone. Maddening... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345713/select-a-poster-frame-for-video-thumbnails-in-photos-app