# How can I set a poster frame for a video in Photos.app in MacOS Monterey?

Tags: video, photos.app, monterey

I'd like to set the poster frame for some of my videos to make it easier to see what they are at a glance. As [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370217/11533) describes, this used to be possible using the gear menu and then later using a pop-up on the timeline in edit mode.

In MacOS Monterey, neither of these options seem to work. The timeline editor still behaves the same way, but the popup to set the poster frame doesn't exist:
[image: Photos.app timeline editor with no poster frame popup]

Sometimes if I drag the start time around and then exit the editor the poster frame changes, but it doesn't seem to happen reliably or predictably.

How can I set the poster frame for a video with Photos.app in MacOS Monterey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Edit" mode, select the frame in the video you want as poster frame, then click the menu item "Image" and select "Make Poster Frame".  Click "Done".

These instructions can also be found at Apple's support pages:
[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/sq-al/guide/photos/pht427071907/mac)

> Select a video frame as a Poster Frame: Drag the playhead to the frame
> you want, then choose Image > Make Poster Frame.

Additionally I just want to point out that the "Help" menu has become very helpful, especially for finding menu items.  For example clicking "Help" and typing "Poster" into the search field, will come up with an arrow overlay, pointing out the menu item(s), fitting the search term.

Comment: This did it! They make it just a little bit less convenient with each version.